# I'm having problems writing a code with String Arrays

Tags: java

So I have to write a piece of code that manages an event. There are 4 events with limited seats. I'm supposed to write string arrays for each one. The program will then add the name to the pertaining string. My problem is I don't know how to keep adding values to a String array using a loop without deleting the previous values. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Assignment_1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    String [] Hockey_Game;
    Hockey_Game = new String[10];

    String [] Turner_Concert;
    Turner_Concert = new String [5];

    String [] Cats_Play; 
    Cats_Play = new String [3];


    String [] StarTrek_Convention;
    StarTrek_Convention = new String [3];

    System.out.println("Which Event would you like to purchase a ticket for?");
    System.out.println("1. Hockey Game 2. Tina Turner Concert \n"
                        + "3. Cats Play 4. Star Trek Convention");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter your first and last name");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = scan.nextLine();




    for (int i = 0; i < Hockey_Game.length; i++){
        Hockey_Game[i] = name; 
    } 


        for (String x: Hockey_Game ){
         System.out.print(x +",");
    }
```

Comment: Please show us the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Corrected tags on this question. This code is Java, not JavaScript. You should only tag the questions with the name of the language you're using. Any other tags are excessive.

Comment: This is supposed to run for 4 users continuously. I'm not sure how to loop that process as well. Sorry this is my first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to loop for 4 users (as per your comment), you should have a loop around the whole input process:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    // read the input
    // add name to correct array
}
```

You should keep counters for each of your event types:

```
// here come all your variable declarations 

// declare the counters
int hockeyCounter = 0;
int tinaCounter = 0;
int catsCounter = 0;
int startrekCounter = 0;

// no need to redeclare the keyboard all the time, just once is enough
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.println("Which Event would you like to purchase a ticket for?");
    System.out.println("1. Hockey Game 2. Tina Turner Concert \n"
                    + "3. Cats Play 4. Star Trek Convention");
    int input = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter your first and last name");
    String name = scan.nextLine();

    switch (input) {
      case 1: Hockey_Game[hockeyCounter++] = name; break;
      case 2: Turner_Concert[tinaCounter++] = name; break;
      case 3: Cats_Play[catsCounter++] = name; break;
      case 4: StarTrek_Convention[startrekCounter++] = name; break;
      default: System.out.println(input + " is not a valid input");
    }
}
```

Is this now perfect? No, not quite. There are still some problems:

1. I didn't account for the maximum number of available tickets. This code will crash if all customers want a ticket to the cats' play.
2. There is a lot of code duplication. It already annoyed me enough to ignore the previously mentioned problem.
3. Variable names should *always* start with a lowercase (and preferably use camelCase). This is a Java convention, which helps other people read your code.

It would be better to somehow solve all these problems at once. For this I would propose an array of arrays (although that is maybe more complicated for a beginner, but would make the code much simpler):

```
final int EVENT_COUNT = 4;
final String[] EVENTS = { "Hockey Game", "Tina Turner Concert", 
                          "Cats Play", "Star Trek Convention" };
final int[] LIMITS = { 10, 5, 3, 3 };

String[][] buyers = new String[EVENT_COUNT][];
int[] counters = new int[EVENT_COUNT];

for (int i = 0; i < EVENT_COUNT; i++) {
    buyers[i] = new String[LIMITS[i]];
}

final int CUSTOMER_COUNT = 4;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 0; i < CUSTOMER_COUNT; i++) {
    System.out.println("Which Event would you like to purchase a ticket for?");
    for (int j = 0; j < EVENT_COUNT; j++) {
        System.out.print((j+1) + ". " + EVENTS[j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    int input = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (input < 1 || input > EVENT_COUNT) {
        System.out.println(input + " is not a valid choice");
        i--;
    } else if (counters[input-1] >= LIMITS[input-1]) {
        System.out.println(EVENTS[input-1] + " is sold out!");
        i--;
    } else {                
        System.out.println("Please enter your first and last name");
        buyers[input-1][counters[input-1]++] = scan.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome bro! Well the customers can buy up to 2 of any one event. Also they can be placed in a waiting list. The waiting is is up to 2 spots. I need to run this until all the events are filled up. Thanks by the way for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This should be doing what you're looking for...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment_1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] Hockey_Game;
    int numHockey = 0;
    Hockey_Game = new String[10];

    String[] Turner_Concert;
    int numConcert = 0;
    Turner_Concert = new String[5];

    String[] Cats_Play;
    int numPlay = 0;
    Cats_Play = new String[3];

    String[] StarTrek_Convention;
    int numCon = 0;
    StarTrek_Convention = new String[3];
    for (int user = 0; user < 1; user++) {
        System.out
                .println("Which Event would you like to purchase a ticket for?");
        System.out.println("1. Hockey Game 2. Tina Turner Concert \n"
                + "3. Cats Play 4. Star Trek Convention");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter your first and last name");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = scan.nextLine();

        switch (input) {
        case 1:
            if (numHockey < Hockey_Game.length) {
                Hockey_Game[numHockey] = name;
            }
            numHockey++;
            for (int j = 0; j < numHockey; j++) {
                System.out.print(Hockey_Game[j] + ",");
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (numConcert < Turner_Concert.length) {
                Turner_Concert[numConcert] = name;
            }
            numConcert++;
            for (int j = 0; j < numConcert; j++) {
                System.out.print(Turner_Concert[j] + ",");
            }
            break;
        // ... continue for last two ...
        }
    }
}
}
```

I do agree with the other answerer that you should be using List/ArrayList for this, but if the purpose of the assignment was to use arrays, here's how you could do it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use String[] use List

```
List<String> event1 = new List<String>();
. . .
event1.add(name);
```

Also define an int[] (this time an array would suffice) that holds the maximum slots for each event, that way when the customer asks for a spot on an already maxed out event you can give him the bad news.

Comment: There's a good chance he is supposed to use arrays specifically.

Comment: What's the difference between the List and the way I did it? Not such a pro at java yet lol. But thanks for looking into it =). And what you mean by the int, I thought I declared the space for the Array in the String.

Comment: It's only string arrays, sad part is it's an online class and the teacher forgets he is teaching them. Greatly appreciate all the help guys.

Comment: @redFive He can always to event1.ToArray()

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is I don't know how to keep adding values to a String array using a loop without deleting the previous values.

Given the following string array definition:

```
String[] sa = new String[3];
```

You can replace existing elements' values...

```
sa[0] = "test";      // index 0 = "test"
sa[1] = "another";   // index 1 = "test", index 1 = "another"
sa[1] = "different"; // index 1 = "test", index 1 = "different"
```

You can append to a String array element just like a normal string...

```
sa[2] = "123";  // index 2 = "123"
sa[2] += "456"; // index 2 = "123456"
```

Now you can do either of those things in a loop as you see fit...

```
for (int i = 0; i < sa.length; i++) {
    String userInputVar = getUserInput();
    sa[i] = userInputVar; // replace value
    sa[i] += "foo";       // append to value
}
```

Comment: Nice, the problem is this is to be automated by a loop. 4 customers and they make orders back to back.

Comment: @user2904895 I just updated my answer to talk about how to use these techniques in a loop. I believe this answers your question. If not, please update your question with more details so we can assist you further.